# Change cell colour in kableExtra across multiple columns using conditional statements (case_when)

Tags: r, dplyr, kableextra

I have a table with multiple `character` variables (named First, Second etc.) Each of these variables contain a number of possible strings (e.g. "DBP", "Low PA"). I want to assign a background colour to each of these strings (e.g. "DBP" or "SBP = red, "Low PA" = blue).

I'd like to be able to this is one `mutate` statement, rather than writing seperate `case_when` statements for each column:

```r
df1 = data.frame(year = c(2014, 2015, 2011, 2013),
                 outcome = c("decline", "death", "death or decline", "decline"),
                 "First" = c("DBP", "Cholesterol", "Low PA", "CRP"),
                 "Second" =  c("SBP", "CRP",NA ,NA ),
                  "Third" = c("Low PA", "SBP", NA, NA))
df1 = data.frame(lapply(df1, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1[is.na(df1)] = ""
df1%>%
  kbl("latex", longtable = TRUE, escape = F, booktabs =  T)%>%
  mutate(across(c(3:5)), column_spec (., background = case_when(. == "SBP" ~ "red",
                                                                    . == "Low PA" ~ "blue",
                                                                    . =="CRP" ~ "gray",
                                                                    TRUE ~ "white")) )%>%
  kable_styling(latex_options= c( "repeat_header"), font_size =10,repeat_header_method =  "replace")
```

This is one example that I have tried. For this I get error:
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "knitr_kable".

The following code works for one column ("First")

```
df1%>%
  kbl("latex", longtable = TRUE, escape = F, booktabs =  T)%>%
  column_spec(3 , background = case_when(df1$First == "DBP" ~ "red",
                                                df1$First == "SBP" ~ "red",
                                                df1$First == "Low PA" ~ "blue",
                                                df1$First =="CRP" ~ "gray",
                                                TRUE ~ "white"))%>%
  kable_styling(latex_options= c( "repeat_header"), font_size =10, repeat_header_method =  "replace")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `purrr::reduce` (or `Reduce` from base R) like so:

```
df1 %>%
  kbl("latex", longtable = TRUE, escape = F, booktabs = T) %>%
  purrr::reduce(3:5, function(x, y) {
    col <- df1[, y]
    column_spec(x, y, background = case_when(
      col == "SBP" ~ "red",
      col == "Low PA" ~ "blue",
      col == "CRP" ~ "gray",
      TRUE ~ "white"))
  }, .init = .) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"), font_size = 10, repeat_header_method = "replace")
```

[image]

Comment: that's great. In my full code I was also using `str_detect(df1$First, "(?i)cholesterol") ~ "yellow"` as a condition in my `case_when` statement  because sometimes I have additional text in the same cell, so can't use `== "cholesterol"`. When I tired changing this to `str_detect(col, "(?i)cholesterol") ~"yellow"` and adding to your `reduce` suggestion i get: `# Warning in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts...` Any ideas?

Comment: Hm. Unfortunately no. I just tried adding the str_detect. Works fine and does not throw a warning on my machine.

Comment: yes it works for my mwe, but for my full data i get the error: `! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.125 #
       # Warning in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts...` There aren't any `#` in my data.frame.

Comment: don't know if you can help further. I've put a `dput` of my real data in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68815269/str-detect-within-purrrreduce-function-for-changing-multiple-column-background